# ACF filter to customize WYSIWYG field wrapper attribute - width

Tags: php, wordpress, filter, advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to customize the ACF field widths via load_fields filters for certain field types. I successfully customized the image type with:

```
function acf_image_width($image_width) {
$i_width = '40';
if(empty($image_width['wrapper']['width'])) {
$image_width['wrapper']['width'] = $i_width;
} }
add_filter('acf/load_field/type=image','acf_image_width', 10);
```

This is pre-populating the image type wrapper attribute width with a value of 40.

For the WYSIWYG field, I did the same but I'm getting an error. I did this but I'm sure I'm getting the field type wrong for WYSIWYG.

```
function acf_wysiwyg_width($content_width) {
$c_width = '60';
if(empty($content_width['wrapper']['width'])) {
$content_width['wrapper']['width'] = $c_width;
} }
add_filter('acf/load_field/type=wysiwyg','acf_wysiwyg_width', 10);
```

I have tried `acf_the_content` and that did not work either. Any help with the field type is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the `acf/load_field` filter, as per the documentation link below...

https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf-load_field/

The `acf/load_field` filter function parameter is...

- `$field` `(array)` The field array containing all settings.

So both of your function params are wrong. Don't be defining `$image_width` and `$content_width` as your functions parameter, as this will just confuse things, because you are actually passing full `$field` settings as an array.

Just pass `$field` param array as `$field` instead, knowing the `acf/load_field` filter will pass the field settings into `$field` param as an array.

Then use `$field` array to update, set or override current array values, and make sure you always return `$field` at the end of your `acf/load_field` filter function...

```
function acf_wysiwyg_width($field) {

  // dump field param contents so you can see the returned data
  // remove 2 lines below once your happy you know what your setting
  var_dump($field);
  exit;

  // then use $field param like this to override the array value (if these keys actually exist)
  $field['wrapper']['width'] = 60;

  // you must always return function param $field for acf/load_field filter to finish the job!
  return $field;

}
add_filter('acf/load_field/type=wysiwyg','acf_wysiwyg_width', 10);
```

---

So in my IDE (PhpStorm)

Above my `acf_wysiwyg_width` function if I type this...

```php
/**
```

Then hit `enter/return`, it generates these PHP comments...

```php
/**
 * @param $field
 * @return void
 */
```

So upon following any WP or ACF  docs on what variable param type is being passed and returning, in this case for example I would specify `(array)` on passed param and return type (also added `@see` with docs url for reference to the documentation I am following for this filter/action function...

```php
/**
 * @see https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf-load_field
 * @param $field (array)
 * @return $field (array)
 */
function acf_wysiwyg_width($field) {

    // then use $field param like this to override the array value (if these keys actually exist)
    $field['wrapper']['width'] = 60;

    // you must always return function param $field for acf/load_field filter to finish the job!
    return $field;

}
```

OK the `add_filter` part, the number `10` is the priority in when this filter is hit.

```php
add_filter('acf/load_field/type=wysiwyg','acf_wysiwyg_width', 10);
```

But when a second the `integer` in the `add_filter` call is set, it means the number of parameters passed in the function, so in the above example only `1` param `$field` is passed, which means you do not need to declare a single passed `filter/action` param.

But if the `add_filter` call had `2` params to pass for example using this `acf_wysiwyg_width` function, then you would need to define anything above `1` passed param into your `add_filter` call like this...

```php
/**
 * @param $field (array)
 * @param $name (string)
 * @return $field (array)
 */
function acf_wysiwyg_width($field, $name) {

  // ...

  // return field array
  return $field

}

// 2 params $field and $name being passed through filter with priority 10
add_filter('acf/load_field/type=wysiwyg','acf_wysiwyg_width', 10, 2);
```

Can be a little confusing but look carefully at https://developer.wordpress.org/ documentation for `filter/action` priorities, parameter and return types. Same with all third party docs like ACF.

Comment: Thanks that worked. I understand `$field` is passed as an array.

Comment: Nice one, always check the docs for every wp or acf function so you know what the parameter passing. When I use filters I always set the function parameter as the default just so I know what I am working with. I will post example of how I comment functions so I know what the variable param and return type is. Might be good practice for you to do the same. 